# Listing Texts of Which Custom Field is Null

Tags: categories, custom-field

I'm using the code below for adding checkbox as a custom field.

The texts selected via checkbox will be counted as "special texts" and the other ones  will remain as "ordinary texts".

```
<?php
add_action("admin_init", "checkbox_init");

function checkbox_init(){
add_meta_box("checkbox", "Checkbox", "checkbox", "post", "side", "high");
}

function checkbox(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$field_id = $custom["field_id"][0];

echo '<label>Check for yes</label>';
$field_id_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_id', true);
if($field_id_value == "yes") {
    $field_id_checked = 'checked="checked"';
}
echo ' <input type="checkbox" name="field_id" value="yes" '.$field_id_checked.' />';
}

// Save Meta Details
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
  global $post;

  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
     return $post->ID;
  }

update_post_meta($post->ID, "field_id", $_POST["field_id"]);


}

?>
```

---

And for listing in the field where the categories are added, I'm using this code:

```
<?php
if( is_category($categories->cat_ID) ) {
  if(!$wp_query) {
    global $wp_query;
  }
  $args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'field_id',
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
  );
  query_posts( array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query ) );
}
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


/***/ - posts -  /***/



<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As a result, the texts that were selected via checkbox are assigned to "yes" and I can list them. But I can't list the texts which were not selected. I think they are
null by default.
I tried 'meta_value' => '', or 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' but it doesn't work.

I'm not good at Wordpress, also my English is not very good. Could you please explain very basically? Thank you.

[image: category]

Comment: [Unchecked checkboxes are critical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239536/how-get-value-for-unchecked-checkbox-in-checkbox-elements-when-form-posted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't let the fields be set to null or unset altogether. The queries needed to get that data are not efficient. Set your field to "no" or some other value.

```
function save_details(){ 
  global $post; 
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) { 
    return $post->ID; 
  }

  $valid = array(
    'yes' => 'yes',
    'no' => 'no'
  );
  if ( isset ( $_POST["field_id"] ) && isset($valid[$_POST["field_id"]]) { 
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_id', $valid[$_POST["field_id"]]); 
  } else {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_id', 'no');
  }
}
```

[Please sanitize that `POST` data!](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) In the code above I used a "whitelist" technique. User input never actually hits the database.

You can then query for the "no"s just as you did for the "yes"es.

If you don't want to take my advise, the query to get the unset/null ones is:

```
$args = array(
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'field_id',
      'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    )
  )
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($q->request); // debug
var_dump(wp_list_pluck($q->posts,'post_title')); //debug
```

And please, please, please do not use `query_posts()`. [Even the Codex says not to.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)